# Is there an easy way to get something like Keras model.summary in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have been working with Keras and really liked the `model.summary()`
It gives a good overview of the size of the different layers and especially an overview of the number of parameters the model has.

Is there a similar function in Tensorflow? I could find nothing on Stackoverflow or the Tensorflow API documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything like model.summary() for the tensorflow... However, I don't think you need it. There is a TensorBoard, where you can easily  check the architecture of the NN.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard

[image]
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz

Comment: how to know each layer's shape and number of params with tensorboard?

Comment: This does not answer the OP question.

Comment: @BiBi it is! see the question `something like Keras model.summary`

Answer (score 62):

Looks like you can use [Slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim)

Example:

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.layers import base
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

x = np.zeros((1,4,4,3))
x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, np.float32)
z_tf = tf.layers.conv2d(x_tf, filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3))

def model_summary():
    model_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    slim.model_analyzer.analyze_vars(model_vars, print_info=True)

model_summary()
```

Output:

```
---------
Variables: name (type shape) [size]
---------
conv2d/kernel:0 (float32_ref 3x3x3x32) [864, bytes: 3456]
conv2d/bias:0 (float32_ref 32) [32, bytes: 128]
Total size of variables: 896
Total bytes of variables: 3584
```

Also here is an example of custom function to print model summary:
https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan/blob/f3a044621e2ab802d40940c16cc86042ae87e100/dnnlib/tflib/network.py#L507

If you already have `.pb` tensorflow model you can use: [inspect_pb.py](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/blob/master/utils/inspect_pb.py) to print model info or use tensorflow [summarize_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#inspecting-graphs) tool with `--print_structure` flag, also it's nice that it can detect input and output names.

Comment: For some reason, this only gives me variable size and information.

Comment: @Blade Which one?

Comment: The model_summary() function.

Comment: This also works for TensorFlow Lite models! (It seems that this is only if they were built using TensorFlow however)

Comment: what about layer outputs as well?

Comment: Slim isn't available anymore in Tensorflow

Comment: To obtain Slim module removed from tensorflow 2, please visit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628439/upgrading-tf-contrib-slim-manually-to-tf-2-0
to find the solution

Answer (score -2):

You can use keras with the tensorflow backend to get the best features of either keras or tensorflow.

Comment: Understand, however, I have existing models in Tensorflow (e.g. programmed by others) which I would like to understand better and therefore, I'm looking for a way to get more output from Tensorflow.

Comment: The best way to look at tensorflow training is by adding summaries to your code and using tensorboard.

Comment: Is there a quick way to convert tensorflow model or graph into keras model and then we can just do model.summary(). Really missed this quick textual way, (understood there's tensor board.)

Comment: You can go from keras to tf but not the other way around as tf graph is lower level than keras graph.

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't provide an answer with a solution to the problem ("just don't use X but Y instead" rather qualifies as advice).