# Display Tensorflow Model Summary as like in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

We can build the model with tensorflow layers. Is there any way we can display the model summary as like in Keras.

[Keras Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLspJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to get something like Keras model.summary in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560313/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-something-like-keras-model-summary-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such option. TensorFlow is a lot more generic than Keras and allows arbitrary graph architectures, so showing such a structured summary does not make sense for arbitrary TensorFlow graphs. The closest is probably TensorBoard, which has a very handy interactive [graph visualization tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz).

Comment: This is probably the best answer there is. The only answer that explains why it is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

Keras is part of TensorFlow (for some time) so you can always get nice things like:

```
model.output_shape # model summary representation
model.summary() # model configuration
model.get_config() # list all weight tensors in the model
model.get_weights() # get weights and biases
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Read the question, the question properly before blindly answering. The OP wants to know if there is a method like `model.summary()` for pure TensorFlow.