# How to visualize a Tensorflow Model from its summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, modelsummary

I am working with a custom Tensorflow model (not a Keras object) with a mostly unknown structure, and I printed the summary with this (taken from [Is there an easy way to get something like Keras model.summary in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560313/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-something-like-keras-model-summary-in-tensorflow)):

```py
def model_summary():
    model_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    slim.model_analyzer.analyze_vars(model_vars, print_info=True)

model_summary()
```

The result is the following (I am reporting only a part of it):

```
---------
Variables: name (type shape) [size]
---------
model/temb/dense0/W:0 (float32_ref 128x512) [65536, bytes: 262144]
model/temb/dense0/b:0 (float32_ref 512) [512, bytes: 2048]
model/temb/dense1/W:0 (float32_ref 512x512) [262144, bytes: 1048576]
model/temb/dense1/b:0 (float32_ref 512) [512, bytes: 2048]
model/conv_in/W:0 (float32_ref 3x3x1x128) [1152, bytes: 4608]
model/conv_in/b:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
model/down_0/block_0/norm1/beta:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
model/down_0/block_0/norm1/gamma:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
model/down_0/block_0/conv1/W:0 (float32_ref 3x3x128x128) [147456, bytes: 589824]
model/down_0/block_0/conv1/b:0 (float32_ref 128) [128, bytes: 512]
```

How can I convert this into a clearer scheme, like a png that I can visualize? For example:
[image]

EDIT: The graph I'm referring to is the same as the `graph.pbtxt` file here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pm6tn31da21yrx4/AADobrMR1hqHGnVV3SBOMPTJa/diffusion_celebahq_model?dl=0&subfolder_nav_tracking=1

Comment: check- tf.keras.utils.plot_model()

Comment: @V.M my model is not a keras object. Can I convert it? PS you can find the `pbtxt` file at the link in the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

**This diagram was most likely made by a human.**

Labels like "copy and crop" are not typically derived from your raw model, maybe you could train a model for it ;D

There are many frameworks which can visualize your Tensorflow Model, Tensorflow has it's own suite [Tensorboard](https://tensorboard.dev/).

See this [example](https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/EDZb7XgKSBKo6Gznh3i8hg/#graphs&run=lr_1E-04%2Cconv%3D1%2Cfc%3D2):

[image]

If you want anything else, look at [this thread over at Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-do-you-visualize-neural-network-architectures)

Comment: Yes, I have trained a model from it! I am having some troubles plotting the model correctly. You can find the `graph.pbtxt` file here. Can you plot it? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pm6tn31da21yrx4/AADobrMR1hqHGnVV3SBOMPTJa/diffusion_celebahq_model?dl=0&subfolder_nav_tracking=1